# Declaring a member variable that takes a constructor parameter

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, declaration, member-variables

```
 // In A.h
 class A
 {
  public:
    enum eMyEnum{ eOne, eTwo, eThree };
  public:
    A(eMyEnum e);
 }

 // In B.h
 #include "A.h"
 class B
 {
    B();
    private:
       A memberA;
 }

 // In B.cpp
#include "B.h"
 B::B(void) : memberA(A::eOne)
 {}
```

The declaration to 'memberA' gives me a compile error using the g++ compiler:
error: 'A::eOne' is not a type

How can I overcome this? Do I simply need to create a default constructor that takes no parameters?

Comment: Is `memberA` a member variable or a member method?

Comment: memberA is supposed to be a member variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to initialise a member variable.  You could do something like:

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : memberA(A::eOne) {}  // Initializer list in constructor
private:
    A memberA;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this earlier, but it gives me link errors:
undefined reference to 'A::A(A::eOne), even though I do have a definition for it.

Comment: @lost_bits: Well, that's a different issue.  Edit your post to include your *actual* code...

Comment: sorry! I forgot to remove the parameter in the member variable declaration.

Comment: sorry - the link errors were my fault - i did not update my makefile correctly, your solution fixed the compile errors though. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(A::eMyEnum someValue = A::eOne) : memberA(someValue) {};

    private:   
    A memberA;
}
```

Comment: hmm - unfortunately I don't want to have to modify the constructor for class B, as it wouldn't make sense in my particular design.

Comment: you'll have to modify the constructor for class B, because that's where you have to initialize memberA.  Think about it - at what other point would memberA be initialized if not at the time the B is constructed?  Get rid of the argument if you don't like it, but it won't break anything, and it's really the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`A` constructor expects a `eMyEnum`. It is not clear why you would want `B`'s constructor to not accept an `eMyEnum` parameter too. Anyway, *assuming* that your aim is to pass the argument to `A`'s constructor as `A::eOne` (as opposed to `A::eMyEnum::eOne`), you could try the following code, which uses `typedef`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    typedef enum { eOne, eTwo, eThree } eMyEnum;
public:
    A(eMyEnum e) {
        cout << "A ctor" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B() : memberA(A::eOne) {
        cout << "B ctor" << endl;
    }
private:
    A memberA;    

};

int main() {
    B b;
}

// output
A ctor
B ctor
```

However, notice that `memberA`'s constructor is always called with the argument as `A::eOne`. You have not showed how this argument is used in the constructor, but I presume that in your real code it initialises a member of `A`. If the member must always have the same value, make it `const` and remove the parameter from the constructor.

Comment: thanks , yes this would work! I ended up accepting Oli's answer though as he was just first. Thank-you though, appreciate it!

Comment: I am glad you found it useful. No worries about accepting the answer. I just happen to live in a different time zone. Bad luck!

Answer (score 0):

eOne is not the type, eMyEnum is the type.  What you're essentially saying is that "You must pass the literal 2 into this method" - it doesn't make any sense.  If you don't mean to pass an enum into it, you'll have to clarify what you were going for.

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to pass an enum into memberA, since the constructor for class A requires it.