# Constructor w/Multiple Arguments in Constructor list not working C++

Tags: c++, xcode, constructor, g++, initialization

I'm trying to compile class A, which has a member of class B, where class B has no default constructor and its only constructor requires multiple arguments. Simple, right? Apparently not...

Class A:

```
class SessionMediator
{
 public:
  SessionMediator()
      : map_(16,100,100)
  {}

  Tilemap map_, background_, foreground_;
};
```

Class B:

```
struct Tile2D;

class Tilemap
{
 public:
  Tilemap(const unsigned int tile_size, const unsigned int width, 
          const unsigned int height)
      : tiles_(NULL), tile_size_(tile_size)
  {
    Resize(width, height);
  }

  inline void Resize(const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height)
  { /* Allocate tiles & assign to width_, height_... */ }

  unsigned int tile_size_, width_, height_;
  Tile2D* tiles_;
};
```

I am instantiating SessionMediator like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  SessionMediator session;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting. I'm compiling in XCode on Mac OS 10.5.8 and the compiler is g++:

```
session_mediator.h: In constructor 'SessionMediator::SessionMediator()':
session_mediator.h:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Tilemap::Tilemap()'
tilemap.h:31: note: candidates are: Tilemap::Tilemap(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
tilemap.h:26: note:                 Tilemap::Tilemap(const Tilemap&)
session_mediator.h:19: error: no matching function for call to 'Tilemap::Tilemap()'
tilemap.h:31: note: candidates are: Tilemap::Tilemap(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
tilemap.h:26: note:                 Tilemap::Tilemap(const Tilemap&)

(Duplicate of above here)
Build failed (2 errors)
```

I wrote a short compilable example doing basically the same thing, to try to figure out what exactly I was doing wrong, which compiles just fine with no errors in g++:

```
class A
{
 public:
  A(int x, int y, int z)
      : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z)
  {}  

  int x_, y_, z_; 
};

class B
{
 public:
  B() 
    : m_a(1,2,3)
  {}  

  A m_a;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  B test;
  return 0;
}
```

Why does it fail in the first example? The 3 arg constructor for Tilemap (in Ex#1) is being called in the same way that the 3 arg constructor for A is being called (in Ex#2).

The code seems pretty much identical to me in the two examples.

Comment: Is there any other constructors that you have? Is line 19 that particular constructor?

Comment: There is another SO post similar to this: 
Declaring a member variable that takes a constructor parameter


http://stackoverflow.com/a/7395203/391693

Comment: Those are the only constructors. I'll look at the other post, I tried hard to find an answer to this question before I posted but most of what I got were basic stuff about how the constructor initialization list works.

Comment: also u r not showing how u r calling `SessionMediator` or `TileMap` like u have shown in `main` method of the example

Comment: Adding a section showing how SessionMediator is being instantiated. It is using the default constructor.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It: Days of favoring inheritance over containment are long gone :-).

Comment: Try to put `map_(16u,100u,100u)` in the SessionMediator constructor call to make the constants unsigned. This is the only thing that comes to mind now :-).

Comment: There's too much guessing going on here.  You have left out some critical piece of information; edit your problem code so that it can be copy/pasted and compiled to produce the error you're running into. As currently posted (after minor fixes, such as forward declaring `Tile2D` and fixing the comment that hides a closing brace), the code code does not produce the error you're asking about with GCC/G++ or MSVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was trying to simplify my example a bit, I accidentally left out two important things: other data members in the SessionMediator class.

The problem was that I had two additional members of the Tilemap class ("background_" and "foreground_"), which weren't being initialized in the constructor initialization list like the first member "map_".

The constructor should be changed to this:

```
SessionMediator()
    : map_(16,100,100), background_(1,1,1), foreground_(1,1,1)
{}
```

I apologize for any time wasted over this question; it turned out to be something much simpler. Hopefully someone else will see this question and realize the mistake they are making.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is if you are using the `copy constructor`:

`SessionMediator a = b;` or `SessionMediator a (b);`

You might get in the situation where the default copy constructor of `SessionMediator` would try to use the default constructor of `Tilemap` which will cause the error you have.

Comment: I'm creating the session mediator object as "SessionMediator session;", if that helps any. But I will look into that...

Comment: Also check for forgotten colon, comma in the constructor or something like that, some spelling mistake.  Also if they are defined in the same file, if `Tilemap`  is declared after `SessionMediator` the compiler would not know about `TileMap` when it reach SessionMediator constructor and that might cause such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `map_(16u,100u,100u)` in the SessionMediator constructor call to make the constants unsigned. This is the only thing that comes to mind now :-).

This compiles fine for me:

```
class Tilemap
{
public:
    Tilemap(const unsigned int tile_size, const unsigned int width, 
        const unsigned int height)
    {
    }
};

class SessionMediator
{
public:
    SessionMediator(): map_(16u,100u,100u){}

    Tilemap map_;
};
```

Comment: This didn't work, but thanks for trying. I've been going over the code, I can't find any obvious syntax errors in either file. I'll let you guys know what the problem was if I find it though.

Answer (score -1):

Well, when you do:

```
 Tilemap map_;
```

You're calling the default ctor - but you don't have one defined, that's the error message.

On the extra:

```
 Tilemap::Tilemap(const Tilemap&)
```

C++ generates a ctor that takes a reference for you. So the valid matches are (1) the one you defined which takes 3 args and (2) the auto-generated one that takes the const ref.

Comment: When he writes `Tilemap map_;`, he is declaring a member.  No constructor is called until the containing class constructor is called; in which case, the constructor of the member is called with the arguments given in the initialization list.

Comment: @TragicPixel: Ahhh subtle, when you intantiate B, it calls "B() : m_a(1,2,3)" - calling the 3 arg ctor for A; if you remove the ":m_a(1,2,3)" it should fail nicely ;-)

Comment: @MarkStevens But I'm instantiating map_ in the same exact way as I instantiate m_a: after instantiating SessionMediator, it calls "SessionMediator() : map_(1,2,3)" calling the 3 arg ctor for Tilemap. Which is exactly what is happening in the second example.

Comment: @TragicPixel: Sorry, maybe it's a compiler difference, but both examples compile correctly for me with VS2010, and both fail to compile if I remove the call to the 3 argument ctor (with the "no appropriate default constructor" error). Sorry, I think I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for the effort anyway!